# Using arguments in python

Tags: python, arguments

I wrote a code using Python in Geany within windows and I'm using arguments in the code. I execute the program within the Geany so I don't know how to use arguments.
How could I convert the program to be be run as a standalone system, not to be run from within an IDE.

how could I use terminal in windows to run the code like this :

```
John~/home/args -> ./test.py -h
```

Comment: Please, in the future, search for whether other people already asked and answered a question before asking it again.

Comment: No, but I'm trying to provide helpful advice for if you'd rather your questions not be closed for violating site guidelines in the future. If you reject that advice, you're the only person who suffers for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad, write what you would in terminal...

```
python test.py -h
```

Save it as a .bat file... Then you can run the bat file :)

PS. This goes for anything you wish to run in CMD

Comment: Note: full path to file is needed

Comment: is there a way to convert the code to exe ?

Comment: @user3753854, yes, there is, and that's also a separate question already asked and answered elsewhere.

Comment: That will do exactly what your exe can do... Except maybe have an icon image. Just double click and it runs like an exe would